# Mini-SAS Connector Puzzle

Tags: sas, connector

Can anyone clearly define the difference between the Mini-SAS HD SFF-8644 and SFF-8614 connectors please?
The SFF-8644 seems to be the more widely recognised 'male' connector but SFF-8614 seems also to be in use. I cannot find if there is any discernible difference between the two but I don't want to order cables with the wrong type of connector.
The one possibility I have come across is that the 8614 is the 4-lane version and the 8644 is the 8-lane version although it does specify "8-lane with dual connector" which muddies the water somewhat. I would appreciate confirmation of this if anyone knows for sure as this is from Wikipedia ([Serial-Attached SCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI)).
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting question which I thought I would have a go at answering.

Seagate provide a list of the [SFF specifications](https://ftp.seagate.com/sff/8000_PRJ.HTM) but all of the links direct you to the current host, the [Storage Networking Industry Association (SNIA)](https://www.snia.org/technology-communities/sff/specifications). Here we can search for each specification which yields the following.

- [SFF-8613](https://members.snia.org/document/dl/25938) / [SFF-8643](https://members.snia.org/document/dl/25951)
- [SFF-8614](https://members.snia.org/document/dl/25939) / [SFF-8644](https://members.snia.org/document/dl/25952)

If we take a look inside SFF-8614 there is the following note:

> **Update History:**
>
> The content of this specification was formerly contained in SFF-8644, and it was
>   broken out into a separate specification so that it could be referenced by higher
>   speed variations.

*Reading the two specifications my interpretation follows.*

The content which was moved to SFF-8614 discusses the physical form of the connectors; both the "fixed" part (socket) and the "free" part (plug). There's even a heat sink specification for a socket (!).

The content of SFF-8644 which remains is almost nothing. The only purpose I can see to this document now is a link between the physical form (which the document refers to as the "Connector Mechanical") with the SAS-3 PCIe 3.0 Application Interface (what I tend to think of as the electrical specification, or signal specification).

I haven't had time to digest the details but SFF-8644 contains an illustration taken from SFF-8614 and it looks like an SFF-8644 connector may be x4 or x8 and I would assume the cable assembly should specify which (although perhaps x4 is 'normal enough' to go unspecified, with x8 being explicitly stated). I've uploaded a copy of Figure 4-1 General View of Configurations below from SFF-8644 to illustrate.

The SFF-8614 spec also states:

> 2.1 Industry Documents
>
> The following interface standards and specifications are relevant to this
>   Specification.
>
> - INCITS 519 SAS-3 (Serial Attached SCSI 3)
> - INCITS 534 SAS-4 (Serial Attached SCSI 4)
> - SFF-8410 High Speed Serial Testing for Copper Links
> - SFF-8643 Mini Multilane 4/8X 12 Gb/s Unshielded Connector (HD12un)
> - SFF-8644 Mini Multilane 4/8X 12 Gb/s Shielded Connector (HD12sh)
> - SFF-8673 Mini Multilane 4/8X 24 Gb/s Unshielded Connector (HD24un)
> - SFF-8674 Mini Multilane 4/8X 24 Gb/s Shielded Connector (HD24sh)

This makes it slightly more clear that you probably want to buy SFF-864{3,4} or SFF-867{3,4} cables, rather than SFF-861{3,4}. With the 3 variants being un-shielded (presumably internal) and 4 variants being shielded (presumably external).

I hope this helps your understanding. It has certainly helped mine!

[image: SFF-8614, FIGURE 4-1 GENERAL VIEW OF CONFIGURATIONS]